# Adding GLSurfaceView in layout

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to run android samples http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

I have to add some controls like text and buttons to the view which will look like [image: android ui]

How to use GLSurfaceView in Android layout?

**Main Activity** (skipped some auto generated code)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGLSurfaceView = (myGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceViewID); //crashes 
 }
```

**Surface view**

```
public class myGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
private myRenderer mRenderer;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public myGLSurfaceView (Context context) {
    super(context);
     // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);


    // Creating a Renderer
    setRenderer(new myRenderer(context));       

    // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}

public myGLSurfaceView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setRenderer(myRenderer mRenderer, float density) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id= "@+id/linearlayout1" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="A Button" />

<GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glSurfaceViewID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.23" />
```

Answer (score 6):

`GLSurfaceView` isn't any different from other views when it comes to adding it to a layout. The only consideration is that it's mostly subclassed when it's used, like it's done in your code, while that's not quite as common (but also not terribly unusual) for other types of views.

The problem in your attempt is the class name used when adding it to the layout:

```
<GLSurfaceView
    ...
```

Not surprisingly, this would create an instance of the `GLSurfaceView` class when the layout is inflated. But that's not what you want. You want to create an instance of your derived class, which is `myGLSurfaceView`. An obvious attempt to do this would be:

```
<myGLSurfaceView
    ...
```

This is not going to work yet. The class name needs to be qualified with the package name. Say your `myGLSurfaceView` class is part of the `com.msl.myglexample` package:

```
package com.msl.myglexample;

public class myGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    ...
}
```

Then the functional entry in the layout file will be:

```
<com.msl.myglexample.myGLSurfaceView
    ....
```

---

This is not a problem in the OP's code, but since it's a common issue people encounter when trying to do this: It's also critical that your derived `GLSurfaceView` has a constructor that takes an `AttributeSet` as an argument. This is needed for all views that get inflated from XML.

```
public myGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Comment: This should be ok, but it is not working properly because GLSurfaceView must be instantiated with default constructor without attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use child frame layout in layout editor and add custom gl view to it from a code.

```
class MyGLSurfaceView(context: Context?) : GLSurfaceView(context) {
    private val renderer: DiceRenderer

    init {
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2)
        renderer = DiceRenderer()
        setRenderer(renderer)
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY)
    }
}

class PlayActivity : ...() {
    private var mySurfaceView: MyGLSurfaceView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       ...
        mySurfaceView = MyGLSurfaceView(this)
        val frame = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.someFrameId)
        frame.addView(mySurfaceView)
```