# How to partially draw in opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Drawer {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GLSurfaceView surface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(surface);
    int[] id = new int[]{R.drawable.panorama};
    surface.setRenderer(new SpriteBatcher(this, id, this));
   }

   @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl, SpriteBatcher sb) {
    sb.drawLine(R.drawable.panorama,new Rect(0,0,400,400),10,10,200,200,10);

    }

}
```

I have a situation where i want to draw partially on the screen ,rather than using up the entire screen using opengl. Currently I have written code which renders an image on the glSurfaceView but it takes up the entire screen. I have found that gl.glScissor() can be used to achieve what i want to achieve but I am not sure how to use it since i am new to android and OpenGL in particular.Thank you.

Comment: Might be too obvious, but why are you making the `GLSurfaceView` fill the whole screen if you only want to draw on part of the screen? Can't you simply make it part of the layout?

Comment: @RetoKoradi : That's exactly what my question is, How can i make GLSurfaceView part of my layout?...I know it sounds like  a noob question to you , but i am really new to OpenGL, really need all the help that i can get. Thank you :)

Comment: There are a lot of previous questions if you search for "GLSurfaceView layout". I answered one here, but there should be a bunch of others as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936020/adding-glsurfaceview-in-layout. You can add a `GLSurfaceView` to a layout like any other view. I'm not totally sure if it's necessary to derive from it, but you'll normally do that anyway once your code gets a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks i have found the solution , check my answer out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, here is my code,

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GLSurfaceView surface = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceViewID);
        int[] id = new int[]{R.drawable.panorama};
        surface.setEGLConfigChooser(true);
        surface.setRenderer(new SpriteBatcher(this, id, this));
        surface.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl, SpriteBatcher sb) {
        sb.drawLine(R.drawable.panorama,new Rect(0,0,400,400),10,10,200,200,10);
        }
```

Here's my layout activity_main,

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:divider="#000000"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/glSurfaceViewID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                </android.opengl.GLSurfaceView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

I have used a Library called android-sprite-batcher - https://github.com/twicecircled/Android-Sprite-Batcher